# Loading jar dynamically to Spark driver in Jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I want to load a jar file dynamically to Spark driver in Juptyer (Scala).
The sparkContext.addJar method seems to load it to the executors. Is there a way to load it to the driver?

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, unfortunately - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5377

Answer (score 0):

Add jar to the SPARK_CLASSPATH environment variable before launching spark-shell.

conf/spark-env.sh to include a JAR with your library.

More [details](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spark-users/IBgbLoFWbxw)

Comment: This is in jupyter notebook scenario and I don't have the JAR file before the launch. I  need to load it dynamically as part of execution.

Comment: https://medium.com/@DustinVanStee/how-to-add-a-custom-library-to-a-jupyter-scala-notebook-in-ibm-data-science-experience-dsx-d85e97bc2e10

Comment: %AddJar cmd seems specific to the IBM notebook, not available in the jupyter version I am using (HDInsight)